# Mysql as Json php

Tags: php, mysql, json, web-services, get

I want to have the following output as a Json:

```
{
      "test": [
      {
        "Name" : "Alfreds Futterkiste",
        "City" : "Berlin",
        "Country" : "Germany"
      },
      {
        "Name" : "Berglunds snabbköp",
        "City" : "Luleå",
        "Country" : "Sweden"
      },
      {
        "Name" : "Centro comercial Moctezuma",
        "City" : "México D.F.",
        "Country" : "Mexico"
      }
    ]
}
```

I got this working in php through this code:

```
$arr = array(
"test" => array(
    array(
        "Name" => "Test",
        "City" => "Test",
        "Country" => "Test"
    ),
    array(
        "Name" => "Test",
        "City" => "Test",
        "Country" => "Test"
    ),
    array(
        "Name" => "Test",
        "City" => "Test",
        "Country" => "Test"
    ),
)
);
echo json_encode($arr);
```

But now, I am fetching Data from a server. This Data I want to look exactly like the json above. How can I replace the arrays with the fetched data from each row?

---

I am fetching the data from the server via this code:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM Customer";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
// output data of each row
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {

    $Name1[] = $row["Name1"];
    $Land[] = $row["Land"];
    $City[] = $row["City"];
}

} else {
    $returnValue["RecordsExisting"] = "False";
}
```

---

Thanks

Comment: Please edit your question to show how you are fetching the data from the server.

Comment: This site does not exist to teach you how to complete programming tasks. If you have tried this and encountered a specific issue you should ask about it.

Comment: Don't just downvote? That makes no sense because I did not downvote and instead left a comment which is exactly what you are telling me to do.

Comment: What's wrong is you haven't shown us what you tried. You just said, tell me how to do this thing I need.

Comment: But I have shown you what I tried in my code? I don't get the problem about my question... You meant I didn't include my code for fetching the results from the server?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
$arr = [];
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    $r = [];
    $r['Name'] = $row["Name1"];
    $r['City'] = $row["City"];
    $r['Country'] = $row["Land"];
    $arr[] = $r;
}
```

Then

```
echo json_encode($arr);
```

Note that this **DOES NOT INCLUDE** the `test` key from the beginning.

---

Now, if you really need the `test` there, just do it like this:

```
$foo = array('test' => $arr);
echo json_encode($foo);
```

---

(Not tested, but...)
Since you are using what I assume to be mysqli's [fetch_assoc](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-assoc.php), you don't need to change the keys. There is a workaround that you can take advantage of.
If you use your `select` like this, you might get the same result (it might come in lowercase):

```
SELECT Name1 as Name, City, Land as Country FROM Customer;
```

*You can take a look at some aliases examples from [this](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_alias.asp) page...*

That way you can:

```
while(...
    $arr[] = array($row["Name"], $row["City"], $row["Country"]);
)
// 'test' add part
echo ...
```

Comment: Yes that worked and I get the following output, with city, country and name for every User, but arround it I need the test (see above). How do I achieve it?